# Can I change metric units on CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am sending metric data to CloudWatch, and they were sent to AWS with `StandardUnit.Count` unit, but I later changed them to `StandardUnit.Milliseconds`. On my dashboard in AWS I still see the data in `Count` unit.

Is it possible to force AWS to show it in `Millisecs`, or will it change later? Or should I rename my metrics (I would not like that option)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not have to rename your metric. CloudWatch doesn't really care about your unit all that much. From [CloudWatch Concepts doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html#Unit):

> Units help provide conceptual meaning to your data. Though CloudWatch attaches no significance to a unit internally, other applications can derive semantic information based on the unit.

Units are not tied to a metric, they are tied to each specific datapoint. In your case datapoints will have unit ***Count*** up to one point and ***Milliseconds*** from that point on. This is not a problem as long as you don't use GetMetricStatistics API with a specified unit. If you don't specify a unit, GetMetricStatistics will return data for both units, but if you set a unit, you'll only get the data for the specified unit (see the [API docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_GetMetricStatistics.html) for more detail).

CloudWatch Dashboards will display the last unit they see. In the example below, I was publishing the metric with unit ***Milliseconds*** up until the gap and with unit ***Count*** after the gap (opposite of your situation) and the dashboards are displaying the ***Count*** as unit:

[image]

If I change the range of the graph to exclude the datapoints with ***Count*** unit, graph displays ***Milliseconds*** as unit:

[image]

Comment: I really want your answer to be true for me, but it isn't.  I have not been able to change from `count` I pushed for about 3 minutes, even though I have been pushing as `milliseconds` for hours now.  Still says `count` even if I narrow the graph to last 10 minutes.

Comment: Can you do a GetMetricStatistics call for that metric and check the unit on each data point? Also, how are you limiting the range to last 10 min? Don't use zoom, use the time range selector on the top right in the dashboard.

Comment: I just looked back and it rolled off in the range and now says `milliseconds`.  Thanks!  I had definitely been zooming (shame, shame on me)

Comment: Thanks. I guess this explains why I'm seeing a "Multiple units returned" warning in my legend, after changing units from `None` to `Count`.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps, you can go to Edit > Options, then:

1. Uncheck the "Show units" option.
2. Add custom label into the "Label" field.

Here, for example, I changed the label to "Seconds":

[image: AWS CloudWatch: "Show units" unchecked; field "Label" filled with "Seconds"]

Result:

[image: Line graph showing iterator age in seconds]

Comment: Isn't it still displaying milliseconds with a misleading label?

Comment: No, I used math to convert it to seconds. 86400 seconds = 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

May be someone searching for cloudformation templates for the same.

```
      MetricName: "Duration"
  Namespace: "AWS/Lambda"
  Statistic: "Average"
  TreatMissingData: "notBreaching"
  Period: 120
  EvaluationPeriods: 1
  Threshold: 5000
  Unit: "Milliseconds"
  ComparisonOperator: "GreaterThanThreshold"
  Dimensions:
  - Name: "FunctionName"
    Value: !Ref LambdaAuthorizerFnName
```